# eDirectory query returns unwilling to perform LDAPSearchException

Tags: java, groovy, ldap, ldap-query, edirectory

I'm writing an LDAP query to return every account with a UID on an eDirectory server. These accounts will then be cached into a hashmap for use later. The filter I'm using is (&(UID=*)) but I'm getting the following exception:

```
Caught: LDAPSearchException(resultCode=53 (unwilling to perform), numEntries=0, numReferences=0, errorMessage='unwilling to perform', responseControls={SimplePagedResultsControl(pageSize=0, isCritical=false)})
LDAPSearchException(resultCode=53 (unwilling to perform), numEntries=0, numReferences=0, errorMessage='unwilling to perform', responseControls={SimplePagedResultsControl(pageSize=0, isCritical=false)})
    at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnection.search(LDAPConnection.java:3059)
    at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPInterface$search.call(Unknown Source)
```

This query code works fine if I change the filter to be something more specific like (&(UID=a*)) but it seems to fail anytime it's a query that will return a lot of rows. I double check every query in Apache Directory Studio and they all work there with no problems.

Is there some kind of limit for eDirectory queries? If so, what can I do to get around this limit and cache attributes from every account into a hashmap? I have code working that runs multiple queries for all UIDs starting with a, b, c, etc for the entire alphabet but I'm afraid I may not be getting every account this way.

Comment: can you post your code too ?

Comment: I'm using a custom library that calls the following couple lines: ---------------------- def req = new SearchRequest(ROOT, SearchScope.SUB, filter, null)
              ------ req.attributes = returnAtts ------------------- where ROOT is the base DN, filter is the LDAP filter, and returnAtts is the list of return attributes.

Comment: The filter works for me on LDAP Agent for Novell eDirectory 8.8 SP7 (20705.00). Must be something else you are doing. Try posting some code. Have you tried this using ldapsearch on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

In the comment, you suggest that ROOT is the base DN.  Are you sure that the base DN is correct?

If you enable tracing on the eDirectory server (DStrace with +LDAP flag) and try this query, what do you see?  Likely you will get a more helpful error.  As Jeemster in the comments notes, the query itself is fine, rather you are likely having a different error.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure ROOT is the base DN. I actually don't have access to enable tracing on the server. For my purposes, I used a workaround where I queried all users with last name starting with A then B then C... etc. I agree my issue is something else and appears to be related to returning a lot of results at once.